# How to enlarge a printed page and then reprint as two?

Tags: printing, printer, zoom

I have some printed sheet music on an A4 page and I need to scan it in with my Canon MP620 and then print out to A4 paper on a hp Laserjet M401 at double the size for easy reading. I realize I will have to rotate and print to two separate A4 sheets. What's the best way to do this? I've scanned in at high res to Paint.Net, but not sure what to do next?

Any ideas on the most efficient and best way to do it?

Comment: You can start by being thankful you live in a country with metric paper sizes.

Comment: @soubunmei I don't have a PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open it up in MS paint (yeah, it seems odd), print -> page setup and select fit to  2 by 1 pages (adjust the orientation if it ends up odd). Adjust borders and such, and print.

Comment: Thanks worked great, except I did this instead. http://i.imgur.com/iybkLwP.png